# How to make popup window footer unscrollable

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, html, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a Kendo Window in my project and I populated some fields in it. Although the header act as I want, the scrollbar overflow to footer. I want the window content is scrollable except from Header and Footer as indicated on the image below (footer to be visible as sticky). How can I do this?[image]

**View:**

```
@(Html.Kendo().Window()
    .Name("winCreate")
    .Title("New")
    .Visible(false)
    .Draggable(true)
    .Content("Loading...")
    .LoadContentFrom("Create", "Issue")
    .Modal(true) 
    .Actions(actions => actions
        .Close()
     )      
)



@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Issue", FormMethod.Post}))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="container">

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ProjectID)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ProjectID, new { maxlength = 75, @class = "k-textbox" })
    <br />

    ... //The other staff here

    <div class="modal-footer">
        @(Html.Kendo().Button()
        .Name("btnCancel")
        .HtmlAttributes(new { type = "button", @class = "k-button" })
        .Content("Cancel")
        .Events(ev => ev.Click("closeWindow"))
        )

        @(Html.Kendo().Button()
        .Name("btnSubmit")
        .HtmlAttributes(new { type = "submit", @class = "k-primary k-button"            })
        .Content("Save")
    )
    </div>

</div>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function for resizing the content div:

```
  function ResizeDialog(){
    var h = $("#dialog").height();
    var headH = $("#dialog .modal-header").outerHeight(true);
    var footH = $("#dialog .modal-footer").outerHeight(true);
    var contH = h - headH - footH ;

    $("#dialog .container").height(contH).css("overflow", "auto");    
  }
```

Then call this function on window open and resize:

```
$("#dialog").kendoWindow({
  title: "New",
  draggable: true,
  modal: true,
  height: "80%",
  resize: function() {
    ResizeDialog();
  },
  open: function() {
    ResizeDialog();
  }
});
```

### Working **[DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/epiNA)**

Note, the DEMO does not use MVC, but the basic approach should be the same...

Comment: I have not thought such a kind of approach that set the css properties with javascript. Very nice, thanks...